# Can I export two dataTables into a single pdf with pdfmake

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

**HTML**
I want to export the below two dataTables into a single pdf with single export button. Both the dataTables  have different columns so it cannot be merged.

```
<div class="container" id="exTable">        
      <div class=" mt-3">
        <h2>Basic Table Example1</h2>
        <table class="table" id="example1" style="width:100%">
            <thead class="table-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>User Priority</th>
                <th>Average MTTR(Hrs)</th>
                <th>Total Number Of Tickets</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1-Critical</td>
                <td>164.12</td>
                <td>182</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2-High</td>
                <td>190.23</td>
                <td>498</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3-Moderate</td>
                <td>908.93</td>
                <td>1511</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>4-Low</td>
                  <td>211.43</td>
                  <td>1817</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
        <h2>Basic Table Example2</h2>
        <table class="table display nowrap" id="example2">
          <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Tower</th>
                <th>CC</th>
                <th>Cluster</th>
                <th>Assignment Group</th>
                <th>Ticket Priority</th>
                <th>Average MTTR(Hrs)</th>
                <th>Total Number Of Tickets</th>
                <th>Incidents resolved Using KO's</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
              <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
              <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
              <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
              <td>1 - Critical</td>
              <td>4.89</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
              <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
              <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
              <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
              <td>1 - Critical</td>
              <td>4.89</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>    
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
 table{
    table-layout:fixed;
    }
    td,th{
    font-size:10px;overflow:hidden;
    }
```

***Java Script***
I want make changes in this dataTable jQuery functions in such a way that if I click on single button both the dataTables data should be exported in same pdf file.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example1').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]   
    });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example2').DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        pageLength : 5,
        lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, 'Todos']],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]            
    });
    });
```

Comment: Have you researched this? If so, what did you find? Were you able to make any progress?

Comment: Example: [Merging multiple pdf Using pdfMake.js in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69802205/merging-multiple-pdf-using-pdfmake-js-in-angular). And more examples [in these search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdfmake+merge+pdf+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: You can access the PDFMake object for each table's PDF using [`customize: function ( pdf ) { ... }`](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdfHtml5). So you have all the raw material you need for a merge.

Comment: Hi @andrewJames, Yes I have researched this and as there is no inbuilt method to generate the pdf in this way, I have to make use customize: function ( pdf ) { }. However I'm not able to get the table data from the 2nd datatable to merge with the 1st one. That is where I needed help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which creates one PDF containing the data from both DataTables in the web page:

1. The first data table is created with no button:

```js
$('#example1').DataTable();
```

2. The second table uses the `customize: function ( doc ) { ... }` [syntax](https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdfHtml5) - the same as I linked to in my comments.

Within that function, we access the data for the first table:

```js
var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable();
```

3. We build arrays for the `headings` row and the `data` rows. This gives us the raw data for that smaller table.
4. We convert this raw data into the format needed to build a PDF table and store it in a `tbl1_rows` array:

```js
var tbl1_rows = []; // the data from the first table
```

5. Finally we clone the PDF table data from the main table, then replace its data with our `tbl1_rows` data - and then we insert this new table object into the PDF:

```js
var clone = structuredClone(doc.content[1]);
clone.table.body = tbl1_rows;
doc.content.splice(1, 0, clone);
```

The end result:

[image]

So, basically, the approach is to just create one PDF for the main table - and splice in the extra data for that additional table, that you also want to display in the same PDF.

Here is the full code for reference:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example1').DataTable();

  $('#example2').DataTable({
    dom: 'Brftip',
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'PDF Export',
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        customize: function ( doc ) {
          var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable();
          var headings = table1.columns().header().to$().map(function(i,e) { return e.innerHTML;}).get();;
          var data = table1.rows().data();       

          var tbl1_rows = []; // the data from the first table

          // PDF header row for the first table:
          tbl1_rows.push( $.map( headings, function ( d ) {
            return {
              text: typeof d === 'string' ? d : d+'',
              style: 'tableHeader'
            };
          } ) );

          // PDF body rows for the first table:
          for ( var i = 0, ien = data.length ; i < ien ; i++ ) {
            tbl1_rows.push( $.map( data[i], function ( d ) {
              if ( d === null || d === undefined ) {
                d = '';
              }
              return {
                text: typeof d === 'string' ? d : d+'',
                style: i % 2 ? 'tableBodyEven' : 'tableBodyOdd'
              };
            } ) );
          }

          // create a clone of the main PDF table (where 
          // content[0] is the PDF's main heading, and content[1]
          // is the main table:
          var clone = structuredClone(doc.content[1]);
          //replace the main table data with the tbl1_rows data:
          clone.table.body = tbl1_rows;
          // insert that cloned table into the main PDF doc, between
          // the PDF title and the main table:
          doc.content.splice(1, 0, clone);

        }
      }
    ]
  });

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.css"/>
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.3/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<div class="container" id="exTable">        
      <div class=" mt-3">
        <h2>Basic Table Example1</h2>

        <table class="table" id="example1" style="width:100%">
            <thead class="table-dark">
              <tr>
                <th>User Priority</th>
                <th>Average MTTR(Hrs)</th>
                <th>Total Number Of Tickets</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1-Critical</td>
                <td>164.12</td>
                <td>182</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2-High</td>
                <td>190.23</td>
                <td>498</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3-Moderate</td>
                <td>908.93</td>
                <td>1511</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>4-Low</td>
                  <td>211.43</td>
                  <td>1817</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
        <h2>Basic Table Example2</h2>
        <table class="table display nowrap" id="example2">
          <thead class="table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Tower</th>
                <th>CC</th>
                <th>Cluster</th>
                <th>Assignment Group</th>
                <th>Ticket Priority</th>
                <th>Average MTTR(Hrs)</th>
                <th>Total Number Of Tickets</th>
                <th>Incidents resolved Using KO's</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>MANUFACTURING 01</td>
              <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
              <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
              <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
              <td>1 - Critical</td>
              <td>4.89</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 02</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 03</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>MANUFACTURING 04</td>
              <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
              <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
              <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
              <td>1 - Critical</td>
              <td>4.89</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 05</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 06</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 07</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 08</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 09</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 10</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 11</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 12</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 13</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 14</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>MANUFACTURING 15</td>
                <td>RICHMOND GROUPS</td>
                <td>Workbrain - Infor HCM Version 6.1.2 - Enterprise Workforce Management</td>
                <td>SN PM USA Workbrain WFM and ETM</td>
                <td>1 - Critical</td>
                <td>4.89</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>0</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Acknowledgements**

I took some of the above approach from the official DataTables source code for PDF exports:

[`buttons.html5.js`](https://github.com/DataTables/Buttons/blob/cc5d3d4fcbc4b53570364f3029121cf575225226/js/buttons.html5.js#L1283)

---

**Update**

For future visitors to this question:

If you want to further format the report, you can take a look at the PDFMake [documentation](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/) and use their [playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) to try different things for yourself.

For example, if you want to add a space between the two tables, you can assign a [bottom margin](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/margins/) to the first table:

```
clone.margin = [ 0, 0, 0, 10 ];
```

More examples: You can change the row striping and cell borders. See [How to remove header in PDF export result from DataTable and change color table fill to white?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67641216/12567365)

Comment: Also, In case if anyone looking to increase the width of first table to 100%. You can add
`doc.content[1].table.widths = 
            Array(doc.content[1].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');`
after the `doc.content.splice(1, 0, clone);`